# Как доработать запрос?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Таблицы: объект, договор, договор-заказчик, заказчик.
Нужно вытянуть id, номер, наименование, дату закрытия объекта и первого заказчика в первом договоре.
Договор содержит id объекта. На 1 объект может быть несколько договоров. Первый договор ищу по самой ранней дате составления договоров.
Таблица дог-зак содержит заказчиков по договору. На 1 договор может быть несколько заказчиков. Первого заказчика определяю по минимальному ID в таблице дог-зак.

```
SELECT obj."ID", obj.nomob, zk.naimzak, obj.naimob, obj.datvk
FROM obekt obj
  INNER JOIN dogovor dgr ON (obj."ID" = dgr."IDobekt" AND dgr.deleted = false)
  INNER JOIN dogzak dz ON (dgr."ID" = dz."IDdogovor")
  INNER JOIN zakazchik zk ON (dz."IDzakazchik" = zk."ID")
WHERE
  obj.deleted = false

  AND dgr."ID" =
    (SELECT dogovor."ID" FROM dogovor
     WHERE dogovor."IDobekt" = obj."ID" AND dogovor."deleted" = false
     ORDER BY dogovor."fdatsost" LIMIT 1)

  AND dz."ID" =
    (SELECT min(dogzak."ID") FROM dogzak
     WHERE dgr."ID" = dogzak."IDdogovor");
```

Написал это, только есть проблема, не знаю как записать следующие условия:
В объекте может не быть договоров(соответственно и заказчика) - этот объект то же должен попасть в результат.
И в договоре может не быть заказчика(не будет записи в таблице дог-зак) - этот объект то же должен попасть в результат.
Подскажите, как доработать эти условия?

Comment: Заменить `inner join` на `left join`. Возможно после доработать условия в части where, чтобы допускали null значения

Comment: @Viktorov а как доработать where?

Comment: похоже, что что-то в духе `and (dgr.ID = .... or dgr.id is null)`. Запоздало думаю, что возможно вообще дорабатывать не надо. Вы проверьте. Просто выполните запрос

Comment: @Viktorov нужно было. Спасибо) Разместите ответ? И, а можно ли оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: Скорее всего от подзапросов можно избавиться используя например оконыне функции. Оправдано ли это будет на самом деле, надо проверять.Размещать ответ с телефона не удобно. Напишите ответ самостоятельно =)

Comment: @Viktorov т.е. оконные функции могут быть быстрее, чем подзапрос? Просто оптимизация нужна в плане скорости выполнения...

Comment: Я не знаю, как работает оптимизатор в Postgree. В Oracle чаще всего оконные функции быстрее, чем коррелированные подзапросы. В вашем случае для каждой строки будет выполнено два подзапроса из where. Скорее всего с оконными функциями результат будет получен быстрее. По хорошему надо смотреть  на планы запросов и произвести замеры производительности.

Comment: Мне кажется, стоит просто попробовать переписать и проверить

Answer (score 1):

`INNER JOIN` - возвращает записи объединяемых таблиц по условию записанному после `ON`. Если в какой-либо из таблиц отсутствует запись соответствующая соседней, то в результат эта запись не попадет. Поэтому меняем `INNER JOIN` на `LEFT JOIN`.
`LEFT JOIN` - возвращает все данные из таблицы "слева", даже если не найдено соответствий в "правой" таблице.
Правка `WHERE`. Добавить `IS NULL` чтобы проверить, является ли какое-либо значение `NULL`.
Результат:

```
SELECT obj."ID", obj.nomob, zk.naimzak, obj.naimob, obj.datvk
FROM obekt obj
  LEFT JOIN dogovor dgr ON (obj."ID" = dgr."IDobekt" AND dgr.deleted = false)
  LEFT JOIN dogzak dz ON (dgr."ID" = dz."IDdogovor")
  LEFT JOIN zakazchik zk ON (dz."IDzakazchik" = zk."ID")
WHERE
  obj.deleted = false

  AND (dgr."ID" =
    (SELECT dogovor."ID" FROM dogovor
     WHERE dogovor."IDobekt" = obj."ID" AND dogovor."deleted" = false
     ORDER BY dogovor."fdatsost" LIMIT 1)
    OR dgr."ID" IS NULL)
  AND (dz."ID" =
    (SELECT min(dogzak."ID") FROM dogzak
     WHERE dgr."ID" = dogzak."IDdogovor")
     OR dz."ID" IS NULL);
```